# Passenger or.. ? Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, debian, passenger

Yesterday I needed to reboot production server on Debian 6 with more than 3-y uptime and 3rd party configured billing system on it. We have no support from that company, and will not have any of it at all, because of "reasons".
Server was never rebooted since configuration was made, as I understand.
Since that, web-interface of billing shows 500 Internal Server Error after successful login. 

I don't know what to do, checked all oracle, billing-system and apache logs. Now I think that I localized the problem, apache log says:

```
[Thu May 12 13:32:18 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Phusion_Passenger/3.0.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ pid=3030 thr=12538160 file=utils.rb:176 time=2016-05-12 16:51:49.463 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner (Bundler couldn't find some gems.Did you run `bundle install`?) (process 3030, thread #<Thread:0x17ea260>):
        from /opt/hydra/rails/arm_isp_old/releases/20120928113940/config/preinitializer.rb:18
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:220:in `preload_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:181:in `initialize_server'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:572:in `report_app_init_status'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:174:in `initialize_server'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb:149:in `start'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:219:in `spawn_rails_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:214:in `spawn_rails_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:213:in `spawn_rails_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:132:in `spawn_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

Interesting things:

- I can't find gems or ruby installed in system at all. When I try to 
  install, apt-get shows too much packages needed to be upgraded, so
  I'm afraid of doing smth worse.
- Env. PATH drops after reboot so I can't call basic utilities, becasuse nothing of /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /bin, /sbin directories are in it.

So. I'm in trouble. Need help.

Comment: I found passenger.conf in apache enabled-mods, there is a string /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/ruby $*
when I'm trying to start it, nothing happens about a few minutes. What does it mean, $*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few very basic things:

1. Looks like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) was used to install ruby. (you can tell by `rvm` in the path of the stacktrace)
2. [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) is failing with an error message `Bundler couldn't find some gems. Did you run 'bundle install'?`. Have you run bundle install? You will probably need to do this from the `/opt/hydra/rails/` directory, so that rvm will set up the necessary environment variables, and so that bundler can find `hydra`'s Gemfile.
3. Is the Rails server being started using `bundle exec`? This will make sure bundler can include the gems from the Gemfile when the rails server starts up.
4. You may not be using the right gemset. Looks like `global` is being used, from the stack trace. Do you have any way of finding out if this is the right gemset to be using? You can run:

   ```
   rvm gemset list
   ```

   to show the gemsets on the machine. Maybe there is one called `hydra` or something like that? You can select a different gemset using:

   ```
   rvm gemset use <gemset name>
   ```

Sorry I can't be of more help. These are ways in which you can end up without Ruby or without gems, and possible fixes. Beyond that, it is difficult to tell from the info provided.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't find rvm with dpkg or else. Seems it's not installed. I don't know how it all was installed, checked history for root, no rvm.

Comment: Found some executable rvm, in /opt/hydra/rails/.rvm/bin/rvm, but it says "Can't find rvm install!". There was some lines in this rvm script, where path checking was. Added path in check line. "which rvm" shows right rvm executable path. But the script still says "Can't find rvm install!"

Comment: if you have found the location of rvm, you could use the line `rvm_path=<path to rvm>` in a `.rvmrc` file to help the script find it, as documented here: https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc .
it would be worth checking for a `.rvmrc` file in your home directory, or `/etc/rvmrc`, or in the project directory, to see if this has been set up already?

Comment: I can't do anything with rvm, it tells me "Can't find rvm install!". Trying now to do smth with it.

Comment: .rvmrc is placed in "/opt/hydra/rails/.rvmrc", copied to my ~, now it works. Well... what's next...)

Comment: good stuff! try `rvm gemset list` to see which gemset you are currently using - look for an app-specific gemset called `hydra` or something. failing that, set the gemset to `global`, as going by the stack trace, that is at least where passenger is installed (`ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global`). also, what happens when you type `ruby -v` now? can you run `rvm list rubies` to see what versions of ruby are on the box?

Comment: It's a pity. It was not a problem for my billing server. I'm searhing further. Thanks!